# AngularJS post request. Character changed from initial value

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I have this very strange problem. I have a very long string as a token for an app. When i`m doing the http post request, the string changes.

From the ending of "Vow== 256220" it is changing to "Vow: = 256220" and i do not understand why.

Here is the code if helps:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: urlWS,
    data: {token: token},0

    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
request.success(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code working for me.

```
 $http({
        method: "post",
        url: urlWS,
        data: 'token='+encodeURIComponent("Vow== 256220"),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
    request.success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

May be above solution solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure `$httpProvider` in your main module config function. This is been done with `transformRequest` method by firstly adding the default header you have added and then transforming the request.

Add the following code to you main config function module:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
// post headers
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {
    return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? $.param(data) : data;
}];
```

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: I am using an app builder bassed on ionic framework and angular. it seems that get requests work, but this one does not... i tried changing to content-type application/json, and it did solve the problem with the characters changing, but the WS I am calling is throwing the same error: "Missing parameter token"